# How do i position this element relative to an image?

Tags: html, css

How do i position this hotspot element to be (0,0) at top left relative to the image whilst maintaining it in the centre of the container?
 
Ive tried several things but it keeps being positioned relative to the container because the image is displayed as block to be centered. But I want the button to be relative to the image not the blocked image..

[image]

**--Update--**

I can make it position correctly if i unblock the image but this uncenters it.
[image]

**HTML**

```
  <div class= "img-container">
    <img id ="img" src = "resources/images/androg.front.jpg">    
<button id="hotspot-button" class="btn btn-fab"></button>
</img>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-container{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#img {
  height: 100%;
  //position: float;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#hotspot-button {
  position:absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.  All you need to do is update your `.img-container` to include this:

```
.img-container{
  display: table;
}
```

This will position the `#hotspot-button` over the top of the image with the coordinates 0,0 from the top, left.

Here is the link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ap83hav5/).

Comment: even with it absolute it doesnt work. it is because the image is as a block. but when i take away the block i cant seem to center it any other way.

Comment: having the image float and the hotspot absolute works. but it uncenters it.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do... hmm.

Comment: I updated my answer to a better solution than setting a % as you stated below.

Comment: this seems to be the best solution in order to maintain the center, however its an anti-hero: http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

Answer (score 0):

ok. i fixed it by manually positioning the container and having the image float and the hotspot absolute.

```
.img-container{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  //vertical-align: middle !important;
  //margin-left: auto;
  //margin-right: auto;
  left: 40%;
}
```

but this is a hack not really a fix imo - since most HTML5 resources i found said that block/margin method is the correct way to centre.

Comment: check my solution. should be enough for you.